# Ninject factory create T based on enum

Tags: c#, ninject

I want to let Ninject resolve an instance of T based on a specific enum input value.

I have read about Ninject's factory extension, but I couldn't find any example having the factory resolve a specific class based on an enum.

Each class derives from a base class and that derived class has several, different interfaces that Ninject also has to resolve.

For example this is how the interface should look like:

```
public interface IProcessFactory
{
    T Create<T>(ProcessIndex processIndex) where T : BaseProcess;
}
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options available to implement AbstractFactory using DI (Ninject).

After analyzing the options, I came up with the solution provided by Mark Seemann, see http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/

The Container Based Factory solution is the one I chose, because:

- Performance: on demand DI resolve on request, no instances loaded in the constructor
- Easy for refactor: when we want to replace the current DI framework (Ninject) to a much better performer with (almost or even better) featureset, the only place to change are the calls inside the factory and not in the NinjectModules/Composition Root.

See also at SO:
[Simple Injector:Factory classes that need to create classes with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961487/simple-injectorfactory-classes-that-need-to-create-classes-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported out of the box. You can customize it by writing your own implementation of [IInstanceProvider](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/Factory/IInstanceProvider.cs)(also see [ninject Wiki entry](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface%3A-custom-instance-providers). Then configure it for your specific factory:

```
kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>()
      .ToFactory(() => new MyCustomInstanceProvider());
```

Or alternatively, if you want to change the behavior of all `.ToFactory()` bindings: Rebind `IInstanceProvider` after loading `Ninject.Extensions.Factory`:

```
kernel.Rebind<IInstanceProvider>().To<MyCustomInstanceProvider>();
```

However, if it's not something you need often i would consider manually writing a factory implementation @ composition root.

Anyway, in both cases you'll need to know how to create a conditional binding. Ninject calls it [Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).
One method is to use Binding-Metadata:

```
const string EnumKey = "EnumKey";

Bind<IFoo>().To<AFoo>()
            .WithMetadata(EnumKey, MyEnum.A);

IResolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>(x => x.Get<MyEnum>(EnumKey) == MyEnum.A);
```

Another way would be to create a custom [IParameter](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/IParameter.cs) and use in a conditional binding:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<AFoo>()
            .When(x => x.Parameters.OfType<MyParameter>().Single().Value == A);
```

Comment: Better to use 
kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory(() => new MyCustomInstanceProvider());
This let's you define which instance provider should be used for a specific factory binding.

Comment: @treze thanks this is a good point i'll include it in my post. What we did however is add some more features to the InstanceProvider which we used in a lot of places. In that case i think it is actually better to provide it "globally" instead of specific per binding.

Comment: If you want it to be your default instance provider it makes of course sense

Comment: No of the supplied solution work. I have a Ninject Module where all bindings are done. I currently have a severe performance issue having a custom ProcessFactory : IProcessFactory, having all the processes injected where the Create method returns the correct injected instance by the enum value. That is not what I want, I want Ninject resolve the correct instance on demand...

Comment: @PatrickPeters can you please explain where the provided solutions fail. The correct instance is resolved and instanciated on demand. The solution doesn't require all implementations of `T` created (injected into the factory) just to create the one you want (specify by the enum).