# Inherit ConstructorParameter from a factory

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm using the Ninject Factory extension. Is it possible to make the ConstructorArguments that are created automatically to have inherit = true? I would like the following to work:

```
kernel.Bind<IFactory>.ToFactory();
```

where IFactory is:

```
public interface IFactory {
    View GetView(object param);
}
```

and param is submitted to View:s dependencies (View will not need it).

I know I can just implement the factory myself, but I was wondering if the Factory Extension had any (undocumented) support for it out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported out of the box.
There's just two things it can do out of the box:

- inject an argument when the parameter name matches
- [perform a named request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945207/684096) (when the `IFactory` method name starts with `Get`)

---

What you could do is write your own customized [`IInstanceProvider`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/Factory/IInstanceProvider.cs).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945207/684096) which describes how to apply your custom `IInstanceProvider`.

The `IInstanceProvider` is the place where you would put such (customized) stuff.
What we did was write a generic instance provider which performs some reflection to detect several custom attributes which were then interpreted to allow several things (inheriting, inject when name matches, inject when type matches, constrained resolution, determine which type will be instantiated, add a parameter to the request,...)

However, for a single application (not as in one piece of software, but rather in one piece of code using it) it's probably not worth it. I'd just implement the factory yourself.

### Custom `IInstanceProvider` with inherited `ConstructorArgument`

```
public class InheritingConstructorArgumentsInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(
        MethodInfo methodInfo,
        object[] arguments)
    {
        return methodInfo
            .GetParameters()
            .Select((parameter, index) =>
                new ConstructorArgument(
                    parameter.Name,
                    arguments[index],
                    true))
            .Cast<IConstructorArgument>()
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

which is then bound like this:

```
kernel
    .Bind<IFactory>()
    .ToFactory(() => new InheritingConstructorArgumentsInstanceProvider());
```

### Unit Test to prove that it works

here's the complete code:

```
namespace NinjectTest.CustomFactory
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using FluentAssertions;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Extensions.Factory;
    using Ninject.Parameters;
    using Xunit;

    public class InheritingConstructorArgumentsInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
    {
        protected override IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(
            MethodInfo methodInfo,
            object[] arguments)
        {
            return methodInfo
                .GetParameters()
                .Select((parameter, index) =>
                    new ConstructorArgument(
                        parameter.Name,
                        arguments[index],
                        true))
                .Cast<IConstructorArgument>()
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public Bar Bar { get; private set; }

        public Foo(Bar bar)
        {
            Bar = bar;
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public string Id { get; private set; }

        public Bar(string id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }

    public interface IFactory
    {
        Foo Create(string id);
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Foo()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel
                .Bind<IFactory>()
                .ToFactory(() => new InheritingConstructorArgumentsInstanceProvider());

            const string expectedId = "Hello You!";

            kernel.Get<IFactory>().Create(expectedId).Bar.Id.Should().Be(expectedId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm running with my own factory for now (just one usage at the moment), but I see that overriding Ninject.Extensions.Factory.StandardInstanceProvider.GetConstructorArguments should be no big deal, if I want the inheritance behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a custom provider, it was quite simple:

```
public class InheritingConstructorArgumentsInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(
        MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        var constructorArguments = new IConstructorArgument[parameters.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            constructorArguments[i] = new ConstructorArgument(
                parameters[i].Name, arguments[i], true);
        }

        return constructorArguments;
    }
}
```

Thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Comment: well thank you for awarding me the accepted answer. I felt that since you did it was necessary for me to add working code as well. Maybe next time you can just edit it into my answer :)
Also for future reference: when you do put code into your question/answer please adjust the formatting (new lines...) so that horizontal scrolling is not necessary.