# Ninject.Extensions.Factory with non-generic type parameter

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I know I can bind the following generic interface with `ToFactory` method.

```
public interface IFoo {}
public interface IFooFactory {
  TFoo Create<TFoo>() where TFoo : IFoo;
}

...

kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory();
```

This code works as expected. However, if I want to use a non-generic variant, I get a Ninject activation exception because it searches for binding of `IFoo`, and so it seems that the factory extension does not recognize the `Type` argument.

```
public interface IFooFactoryWithType {
  IFoo Create(Type concreteType);
}

...

kernel.Bind<IFooFactoryWithType>().ToFactory();
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not supported this way? In my current scenario I cannot use generic version because the type is coming from a runtime parameter. I could use some reflection hack with `MakeGenericMethod` and friends of course but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box. But you can exchange the `IInstanceProvider` with a custom implementation by doing:

```
kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>()
    .ToFactory(() => new MyCustomInstanceProvider());
```

Also see the [wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-custom-instance-providers) for more information.

Furthermore [Ninject factory create T based on enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941052/ninject-factory-create-t-based-on-enum) could be of interested to you.

your `IInstanceProvider` implementation could look like that (i haven't tested whether it actually compiles, sorry):

```
internal class TypeDefinedByArgumentInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override Type GetType(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        return (Type)arguments.Single();
    }
}

kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>()
    .ToFactory(() => new TypeDefinedByArgumentInstanceProvider());
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, and I'm happy to see that it's not too much code either :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly. 
Isn't it that you have to bind IFoo to your concrete type?

```
     kernel = new StandardKernel();
     kernel.Bind(typeof(IFoo)).To<Class2>();
     kernel.Bind<IFooFactoryWithType>().ToFactory();
     var createdInstance = kernel.Get<IFooFactoryWithType>().Create(typeof(IFoo));
```

Comment: In this case no, because there are more concrete types which I request at runtime. I wanted to delegate the request to Ninject with such a factory.