# Ninject equivalent to Autofac IIndex

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

Is there a Ninject equivalent to [Autofac IIndex](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). In other words I need to get a collections of all registered items that have the name of registration.
In Autofac you would do it like so
EDIT: made a change to make things more clear.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Add>().Keyed<ICommand>("add");
            builder.RegisterType<Add>().Keyed<ICommand>("sub");

            builder.RegisterType<Calculator>().As<Calculator>();
            var container = builder.Build();
            var calc = container.Resolve<Calculator>();
            calc.Run();
        }

        public class Calculator 
        {

            IIndex<string, ICommand> commands;

            public Calculator(IIndex<string, ICommand> commands)
            {
                this.commands = commands;
            }

            public void Run() 
            {

                var result = true;
                do
                {
                  var cmd = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                   ICommand command;
                   if (commands.TryGetValue(cmd[0], out command))
                   {
                       result = command.Do(cmd.Skip(1).ToArray());
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Command not found");
                   }


                } while (!result);
            }
        }

        public interface ICommand
        {
            bool Do(string[] data);
        }

        public class Add : ICommand
        {
            public bool Do(string[] data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(data[0]) + double.Parse(data[1]));

                return false;
            }
        }

        public class Substract : ICommand
        {
            public bool Do(string[] data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(data[0]) - double.Parse(data[1]));

                return false;
            }
        }
```

But I was unable to find an how to do this in Ninject.

Comment: Just for the next time you ask a question. Try not to abstract your question to much, because as we can see, the more general you ask a question, the more general the answers will be. And as I have clearly spent a lot of time to help you, its not satisfying, that much of what I have written just missed the *actual question*. So please, if what I have posted lately does answer your question, rewarding it by checking as answer would really be great. - Maybe you should rethink your issue and later ask a more detailed question of your actual usecase. Have a nice evening man.

Answer (score 2):

As in the link provided, you are intending to look up a value by `Key`.

What you are searching for is called [named binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding). Bindings are Identified by a Name. How ever the Problem here is, that you need to use the common injection strategies of ninject.

```
Bind<IDeviceState>().To<OnlineState>().Named("Online");
Bind<IDeviceState>().To<OfflineState>().Named("Offline");

public Modem([Named("Online")] IDeviceState state){
    _state = state;
}
```

This way, you can choose which implementation of `IDeviceState` will be injected by the `NamedAttribute`, which is added right before the injection parameter. But this doesn't fully work out for you, because you want to create `IDeviceState`s on the fly. Thats why you need to use the [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-Referencing-Named-Bindings).

This will allow you to Inject a `IDeviceStateFactory`.

```
public interface IDeviceStateFactory
{
    IDeviceState GetOnline();

    IDeviceState GetOffline();
}
```

Those Factorys underlie a very specific syntax, where `Get`-Methods will resolve a *Named Binding* as described above. So `GetOnline()` will match the `Bind<IDeviceState>().To<OnlineState>().Named("Online")` binding and return an instance of `OnlineState`.

Just tell the `IoCContainer` that `IDeviceStateFactory` is a factory. An implementation of that interface will then automatically be provided by Ninject's Proxy system.

```
Bind<IDeviceStateFactory>().ToFactory();
```

So finally this is how you could imlpement your class `Modem` using this technique

```
public class Modem : IHardwareDevice
{
    IDeviceStateFactory _stateFactory;
    IDeviceState _currentState;

    public Modem(IDeviceStateFactory stateFactory)
    {
        _stateFactory = stateFactory;
        SwitchOn();
    }

    void SwitchOn()
    {
        _currentState = _stateFactory.GetOnline();
    }
}
```

#### Using a real Key

However if you really want to use your `DeviceState`-Enumeration like before, you could use the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945207/4099159).

The Binding Would look pretty much like this:

```
const string EnumKey = "EnumKey";

Bind<IDeviceState>().To<OnlineState>()
        .WithMetadata(EnumKey, DeviceState.Online);
```

Use this Method to resolve using `DeviceState.Online` Key

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IDeviceState>(x => x.Get<DeviceState>(EnumKey) == DeviceState.Online);
```

But in my opinion, there is no reason to do such complicated thing. I recommend you to just forget about the whole `IIndex<TKey, TSource>` mechanics from Autofac and do it the ninject way.

#### Your Edit: preserving IIndex (Solution involving Factory Extension)

Well, as `IIndex` and no such thing do exist in Ninject, you could create your own implementation of it, Inheriting from `IDictionary`, or just define it much alike it and only defining it as follows:

```
public interface IIndex<TKey, TValue>
{
    bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value);

    TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
}
```

The Factory from above then gets `ICommandFactory`

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand GetAdd();
    ICommand GetSubtract();
}
```

then you only need to create an implementation of `IIndex` using the `ICommandFactory` to resolve the actual command instances.

```
public class CommandIndex : IIndex<string, ICommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandFactory _factory;

    public CommandIndex(ICommandFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out ICommand value)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case "Add":
                value = _factory.GetAdd();
                break;
            case "Subtract":
                value = _factory.GetSubtract();
                break;
            default:
                value = null;
                break;
        }
        return value != null;
    }

    public ICommand this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            ICommand value;
            TryGetValue(key, out value);
            return value;
        }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException();}
    }
}
```

But I really need to ask you: Is this whole thing necessary? Man just use the factory. It really gets much less complicated.

#### Another attempt of preserving IIndex without Factory Extension

Another Attempt with propably less coding is directly using the `IKernel` which is propably a slightly bad practice. However you can then resolve *named bindings like this*:

```
public class NamedBindingIndex<TValue> : IIndex<string, TValue>
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NamedBindingIndex(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out TValue value)
    {
        value = _kernel.Get<TValue>(key); // eventually catch an Exception here
        return value != null;
    }


    public TValue this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            TryGetValue(key, out value);
            return value;
        }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }
}
```

Just bind it like this

```
Bind<IIndex<string, ICommand>>().To<NamedBindingIndex<ICommand>>();
```

And then your Solution should be working pretty much as same. Another plus is, that this very last attempt doesn't need no Ninject.Extensions.Factory.

Comment: Yes this is not the same. IIndex returns key value pairs not collections

Comment: This is not a bind time condition it's a runtime condition so that I can run different methods based on keys. The example is just copy from [Autofac site](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html) I have different use case.

Comment: @Filip The Answer does now show how to Inject different implementations depending on _**names**_ which is almost the same as keys. It's the Ninject way of doing this.

Comment: Sorry but as previously mentioned the example is just from Autofac site it's not a real use case. And the point of this is to use a string for the registration so you can execute one based on user input. Most likely I will need to write a custom binder to do this but I was wondering if ninject supported this feature. I will probably just end up extending my interface with a name property so I can select the right one at run time.

Comment: @Filip I just added a way of doing it with the Key you mentionned. - How do you mean *based on user input*. This is a whole new input to your question. However as the solution I provided is absolutely independent from any *user input*, it should be possible to solve your issue this way. Other ways just point out more clearly what you are searching for. As *Jon Skeet* describes in his [blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) it is really frustrating to give good answers, if you are trying to reach a goal which you do not even mention.

Comment: Ok I modified the example to make things more clear but this was more of a question of transferring IIndex to ninject. And is there an equivalent to it in ninject.

Comment: @FilipCordas propably what you search for is `_kernel.Get<TValue>(key)` from the very last example of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with a similar problem I was still unable to find anything similar to IIndex and this was as close as I could do.

```
public static class NinjectExtender
    {
        public const string Index = "INDEX";

        public static IBindingWithOrOnSyntax<TImplementation> Keyed<T, TImplementation, TKey>(this IKernel binding, TKey key) where TImplementation : T
            {
                if (!binding.CanResolve<IIndex<TKey, T>>()) 
                {
                    binding.Bind<IIndex<TKey, T>>().ToMethod(context => new Index<TKey,T>(context));
                }
                return binding.Bind<T>().To<TImplementation>().WithMetadata(Index, key);
            }

    }

    public class Index<T, M> : IIndex<T, M>
    {
        private readonly IContext context;

        public Index(IContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(T key, out M value)
        {
            try
            {
                value = this[key];
                return true;
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                value = default(M);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public M this[T key]
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    var service = context.Kernel.Get<M>(binding => binding.Get<T>(NinjectExtender.Index).Equals(key));

                    if (!service.Equals(default(M)))
                    {
                        return service;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am a bit unsure in if the context is handled in the same way as Autofac but I am not having issues as of now.

```
kernel.Keyed<ICommand, Add, string>("add");
```